# Qt - FormLayout - Qline below Label

Tags: qt, alignment, vertical-alignment, form-layout

I have discovered Qt recently and I search to make a form like this :

[image]

And I succeeded with this code :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication myApp(argc,argv);
  QWidget myWindow;

  // Create Main Box (Vertical) and Line Box (Horizontal)
  QVBoxLayout *mainBox = new QVBoxLayout;
  QHBoxLayout *lineBox = new QHBoxLayout;


  //-------- Box For Name --------//

  QVBoxLayout *nameBox = new QVBoxLayout;

  QLabel *nameLabel     = new QLabel("Name");
  QLineEdit *nameInput  = new QLineEdit();

  nameBox->addWidget(nameLabel);
  nameBox->addWidget(nameInput);

  //------------------------------//


  //------ Box For LastName ------//

  QVBoxLayout *lastNameBox = new QVBoxLayout;

  QLabel *lastNameLabel     = new QLabel("Last Name");
  QLineEdit *lastNameInput  = new QLineEdit();

  lastNameBox->addWidget(lastNameLabel);
  lastNameBox->addWidget(lastNameInput);

  //------------------------------//


  // Add Box to Line
  lineBox->addLayout(nameBox);
  lineBox->addLayout(lastNameBox);

  // Add Line to Main Box
  mainBox->addLayout(lineBox);

  // Finalize and Show Window
  myWindow.setLayout(mainBox);
  myWindow.setWindowTitle("Example");
  myWindow.show();

  return myApp.exec();
}
```

But there is not simpler solution than that...?
It's not possible to use QFormLayout to put label and Qline one below the other...? A vertical alignment...?